# Confirming Location Access in CoronaSDK

Tags: mobile, gps, lua, location, coronasdk

Is there any way to directly request access to the user's location, or is there an event listener of some kind that will notify me once location access has been granted? I'm having a problem related to the use of the MapView object with the Director class and I think it hinges on this.

I have a secondary view with a MapView component in it. When the director class switches to that view, my MapView object is instantiated and I attempt to get the user's location. The problem I'm having is that on my test device (iPhone 4), the attempt to access the user's location takes place before they've granted me location access, so it's only when they leave that screen and later return to it (instantiating it again in the Director library) that I'm able to use their location.

This is obviously unsatisfactory.

Any help/advice?

Answer (score 0):

The solution to your problem greatly depends on your code. You should definitively include the relevant code bits in your SO questions if you want to get help.

I'm going to make a guess and assume that your code looks similar to the MapView example:

http://developer.anscamobile.com/reference/index/nativenewmapview

If that's the case, the problem is that the location is retrieved very late.

```
local function callMap()
        -- Fetch the user's current location
        -- Note: in XCode Simulator, the current location defaults to Apple headquarters in Cupertino, CA
        local currentLocation = myMap:getUserLocation()
        local currentLatitude = currentLocation.latitude
        local currentLongitude = currentLocation.longitude
        ...
```

What you want is that code executed earlier. Ideally, when the application starts. The user will get the "this application wants access to the GPS" message right away, so they will have more time to "approve" before seeing the mapview.

Another thing you can do is using a cache. Store the latest known location somewhere (a config file or the database, depending on your setup). When the connection is lost, or not yet retrieved, show the last known location on the map.

Comment: To clarify, the real issue is that there is no way for me to determine whether or not the user has granted location access before I attempt to get their location. I'm wondering if there's an event, callback, or something of that nature that I can use to respond to the user's approval of my request for location access.

Comment: It doesn't look that way. What are you getting as latitude and longitude when the gps access is disabled?

Comment: Also, try to check the `event.isError` field on the location event. Maybe you can use that. Referenced at the bottom of http://developer.anscamobile.com/partner/mapview

Comment: Maybe I should clarify further/be more precise. I've added a runtime listener for the "mapAddress" event. When the user visits the screen in question, a MapView is instantiated and I attempt to call map:getUserLocation(). Because they have not granted me location access (yet), the call to getUserLocation appears to silently fail and the "mapAddress" event listener is never called. After granting me location access, if they leave the screen and return to it (thereby instantiating a *new* mapView, restarting this whole process), my event listener is fired.

Comment: I understood that. That's why I'm telling you - request the user location once, right when your program starts. Even if the user never creates a mapView. Couple that with caching the last known position, and you will be very well already.

Comment: I'd be very interested in how to fetch user location without a mapView in Corona. Are you sure it's possible to do so?

Comment: @HenrikErlandsson my answer is quite old and possibly outdated now. I suggest opening a new SO question for what you want to know.

Comment: Oh, that's history now, I solved it using an example from the official documentation, I think it was, so it's certainly possible now. :)